# How do I pass a program name from php/html, as a variable to javascript rather than hard coding it in the ' $.get' statement

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, variables

I have a dropdown that uses **`JQuery/Javascript`** within my **`php/html`** program.
This works fine if I hard code the name of the program that runs the SQL to load data into the dropdown list.
I would like this code to be re-usable rather than duplicate it for each dropdown list (I want 2 in the current instance) so I would like to know how to pass different program names as each dropdown list accesses different files. Example: ClubID dropdown requires data from **`clubs`** using **`clubsSearch.php`** but MemberTypeID requires data from **`memtyp`** using **`memtypSearch.php`**.
Here is the Javascript including my latest effort to pass the program name as a variable:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    $('.search-box input[type="text"]').on("click input", function()
    {
        /* Get input value on change */
        var srchName =  <?php echo $SearchName?>;
        var inputVal = $(this).val();
        var resultDropdown = $(this).siblings(".result");
        if(inputVal.length){
            $.get(srchName, {term: inputVal}).done(function(data){
                // Display the returned data in browser
                resultDropdown.html(data);
            });
        } else{
            resultDropdown.empty();
        }
    });
    
    // Set search input value on click of result item
    $(document).on("click", ".result p", function(){
        $(this).parents(".search-box").find('input[type="text"]').val($(this).text());
        $(this).parent(".result").empty();
    });
});
</script>
```

If I use

```
$.get("clubsSearch.php", {term: inputVal}).done(function(data){
```

it works fine.

The relevant section of the form is:

```
    <div class="col-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($ClubIDer)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
        <label>Club ID:</label>
        <div class="search-box">
             <input type="hidden"  name="clubID" value="<?php $SearchName = "\"clubsSearch.php\"";? 
                           >" >   
             <input type="text"  name="ClubID" autocomplete="off"  class="form-control" 
                          value="<?php echo $ClubID; ?>" >
             <?php echo $SearchName?>
                 <div class="result">
                 </div>
            <span class="help-block"><?php echo $ClubIDer;?></span>
            </div>                          
        </div>
  </div>
```

The `**$SearchName**` displays as "**`clubsSearch.php`**" but in Chrome's developer tools I can see the javascript has not recognised the variable **`var srchName = ;`** x  and no dropdown list appears.

Can anyone tell me how to present the search name to the javascript as I am completely unfamiliar with it. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved: In the html
 `<input id="ClubID" data-pgm="\"clubsSearch.php\"">`
and in the Javascript
 `var srchName =input.dataset.pgm`

Comment: Thanks Majid your input set me on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the program name in the data- attr like

```
<select name="WHATEVER" id="WHATEVER" data-program="YOUR_PROGRAM_NAME">
```

in JS get it like

```
var srchName = $(this).attr("data-program");
```

Comment: Thanks - not quite there yet though. This seems to be displaying the same program overlaying the calling program i.e. membersUpdate.php over membersUpdate.php even though I am passing clubsSearch.php. I found the following warning message:  ​ [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.